# How to split a Vec<u8> by a sequence of chars?

Tags: http, rust

I want to extract the payload of a HTTP request as a `Vec<u8>`. In the request, the payload is separated from the rest by the sequence `\r\n\r\n`, that's why I want to split my `Vec` at this position, and take the second element.

My current solution is to use the following function I wrote.

```rust
fn find_payload_index(buffer: &Vec<u8>) -> usize {
    for (pos, e) in buffer.iter().enumerate() {
        if pos < 3 {
            continue
        }
        if buffer[pos - 3] == 13 && buffer[pos - 2] == 10 && buffer[pos - 1] == 13 && buffer[pos] == 10 {
            return pos + 1;
        }
    }
    0
}
```

`13` is the ASCII value of `\r` and `10` the value of `\n`. I then split by the returned index. While this solution is technically working, it feels very unclean, and I was wondering how to do this in a more elegant way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of:

1. A function should almost never have a `&Vec<_>` parameter.

   See [Why is it discouraged to accept a reference to a String (&String), Vec (&Vec), or Box (&Box) as a function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40006219/why-is-it-discouraged-to-accept-a-reference-to-a-string-string-vec-vec-o).
2. Don't use the magic values 10 and 13, Rust supports byte literals: `b'\r'` and `b'\n'`.

As for your question: I believe you can make it a bit simpler using [`windows`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.windows) and [`matches!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.matches.html) with a byte string literal pattern:

```rust
fn find_payload_index(buffer: &[u8]) -> Option<usize> {
    buffer
        .windows(4)
        .enumerate()
        .find(|(_, w)| matches!(*w, b"\r\n\r\n"))
        .map(|(i, _)| i)
}
```

[Permalink to the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2841305c83c997bf506e3e06bf2fac9e) with test cases.

Comment: Thanks a million, @mcarton, that is exactly what I was looking for! Also, thank you for the general Rust advice :)

Answer (score 2):

Note that `slice` has a `starts_with` method which will more easily do what you want:

```rust
fn find_payload_index(buffer: &[u8]) -> usize {
    for i in 0..buffer.len() {
        if buffer[i..].starts_with(b"\r\n\r\n") {
            return i
        }
    }
    panic!("malformed buffer without the sequence")
}
```

I see no reason to use enumerate if the actual element itself never be used, simply looping over `0..buffer.len()` seems the easiest solution to me.

I have also elected to make the function panic, rather than return 0, when the sequence be malformed, which I believe is more proper, though you should probably in the end return some kind of `Result` value, and handle the error case cleanly, if the input be malformed, but you should never return 0 in this case.

Answer (score 0):

A shorter alternative for @mccarton answer would be to use `position`:

```rust
fn find_payload_index(buffer: &[u8]) -> Option<usize> {
    buffer
        .windows(4)
        .position(|arr| arr == b"\r\n\r\n")
}
```